# list base files in a folder with numerous date stampped versions of a file

Tags: linux, bash, find

I've got a folder with numerous versions of files (thousands of them), each with a unique date/time stamp as the file extension. For example:

```
./one.20190422
./one.20190421
./one.20190420
./folder/two.txt.20190420
./folder/two.txt.20190421
./folder/folder/three.mkv.20190301
./folder/folder/three.mkv.20190201
./folder/folder/three.mkv.20190101
./folder/four.doc.20190401
./folder/four.doc.20190329
./folder/four.doc.20190301
```

I need to get a unique list of the base files. For example, for the above example, this would be the expected output:

```
./one
./folder/two.txt
./folder/folder/three.mkv
./folder/four.doc
```

I've come up with the below code, but am wondering if there is a better, more efficient way.

```sh
# find all directories
find ./ -type d | while read folder ; do

    # go into that directory
    # then find all the files in that directory, excluding sub-directories
    # remove the extension (date/time stamp)
    # sort and remove duplicates
    # then loop through each base file

    cd "$folder" && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@%.*}"' _ {} + | sort -u | while read file ; do

        # and find all the versions of that file
        ls "$file".* | customFunctionToProcessFiles

    done    
done
```

If it matters, the end goal is find all the versions of a specific file, in groups of the base file, and process them for something. So my plan was to get the base files, then loop through the list and find all the version files. So, using the above example again, I'd process all the `one.*` files first, then the `two.*` files, etc...

Is there a better, faster, and/or more efficient way to accomplish this?

Some notes:

- There are potentially thousands of files. I know I could just search for all files from the root folder, remove the date/time extension, sort and get unique, but since there may be thousands of files I thought it might be more efficient to loop through the directories.
- The date/time stamp extension of the file is not in my control and it may not always be just numbers. The only thing I can guarantee is it is on the end after a period. And, whatever format the date/time is in, all the files will share it -- there won't be some files with one format and other files with another format.

Comment: well, do you have at least examples of the other possible format? Do they share a pattern?

Comment: The date/time stamp is a configuration option the user can set using formats accepted by `date`. So there is no pattern I can develop around. The only thing I can ensure is its at the end, after the period, and all files will have the same format.

Comment: Um. `date` allows literally **anything** as output.

Comment: Yes. But the script will not allow a user to specify a period in their custom date/time format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find ./ -type f -regex` to look for files directly

```
find ./ -type f -regex '.*\.[0-9]+'
./some_dir/asd.mvk.20190422                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
./two.txt.20190420
```

Also, pipe the result to your function through `xargs` whithout needing `while` loops

```
re='(.*)(\.[0-9]{8,8})'
find ./ -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex "$re" | \
sed -re "s/$re/\1/" | \
xargs -r0 customFunctionToProcessFiles
```

Comment: I updated the question with more details. I forgot to mention that the date/time stamp may not always be just numbers.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how your xargs groups invocations by base file name. It seems to be calling the custom function on every file individually.